# Global namespace population without using new in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was watching the Douglas crockford video on javascript and one the thing that he mentioned was in case you forget to use **new** for class then it will populate the global namespace which in browser is window. I wanted to understand this better so I went and test this out as below

```
var User = function(first,last){
  this.name = first + " " + last;
}

var user = new User("John","Resig");
alert(window.name); // expected to see undefined, but was John Resig
alert(user.name); // this should only show John Resig correctly

var user1 = User("Douglas","Crockford");
alert(window.name); // expected to see Douglas Crockford and shown correctly
```

There is two possibility now, either my understanding of global namespace is wrong or my example is wrong.
Appreciate if you could set me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you sure he didn't say, if you forget to use *var*?

Comment: Why are you using `var User = function(){}` instead of `function User(){}` ?

Comment: Did you run this in the browsers console? And did you run it first without using new? Because here it works as expected: the first is undefined, the second is John and the last is Douglas.

Comment: I'd try running your code again... it's working as it should be for me. http://jsfiddle.net/ExQyG/

Comment: Yes you are right some. I was experimenting few times on the same page. Once I closed the page and loaded again then I got as expected. Thanks a lot

Comment: Using the keyword new is creating a new copy/instance using that constructor. So basically, your User function is creating a blueprint of a user object and calling new User() creates a new copy of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is `this` in the `User` function refers to `window` if `new` isn't used. The default `this` for a function (in traditional JavaScript[1]) is `window`.

[1] Browsers which support `'use strict'` won't behave this way in strict mode. Instead they will throw an exception because `this` is `undefined` if `new`, `apply`, `call`, `bind`, etc. aren't used. See http://jsfiddle.net/ufTq9/

Comment: Thanks Nathan, actually I knew it was supposed to be binded to window in case I did not use "new". I wanted to test it out and then I saw the unexpected behaviour which I later realized thanks to "some" that was due to the fact I was testing on the same page few times. Once I closed it and tested again then I got the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a trick like this one :

```
var User = function(first,last){
   if(this == window)
       return new User(first, last);

   this.name = first + " " + last;
}
var normalUser = new User('first', 'last');
var globalUser = User('fname', 'lname');
// it is undefined :D
alert(typeof window.fname);
```

The thing is that you check if the `new` keyword was used in the construct by checking the scope (the `this` keyword) and if it wasn't (`this == window`) you can force a `new` object to be returned.